# listview android no me actualiza los datos

Tags: java, android

Buenas tengo el siguiente código para cargar un listView en android studio. El cual me muestra los datos sin problemas y me da de alta el usuario con el método del item programado. Pero quiero que cuando me de el usuario de alta me lo quite de la lista. Es decir que se actualize. He leído en otros foros que hay se hacer un setAdapter a la lista seguido de un notifyDataSetChanged(), pero lo pongo en el código y no me hace nada. Alguien me puede ayudar.
El método es el siguiente:

```
// metodo para cargar los datos de la lista
    public void cargaLista(ArrayList<Integer> imagen, ArrayList<String> nombre, ArrayList<String> email) {
        // creamos los array para los datos y le pasamos el tamaño de cada uno por medio del
        // array recibido a traves de la funcion
        imageList = new Integer[imagen.size()];
        nombreList = new String[nombre.size()];
        correoList = new String[email.size()];
        // convertimos los arrayList en array
        imageList = imagen.toArray(imageList);
        nombreList = nombre.toArray(nombreList);
        correoList = email.toArray(correoList);

        // creamos un array para obtener los datos
        for (int i = 0; i < imagen.size(); i++) {
            // creamos la lista con los datos
            listData = new ListData(imageList[i], nombreList[i], correoList[i]);
            // guardamos los datos en un array
            dataArrayList.add(listData);
        }
        // establecemos el adaptador de la lista
        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(AltaUsuario.this, dataArrayList);
        // cargamos la lista
        binding.listViewAltaUsuario.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        // hacemos que se puede pulsar
        binding.listViewAltaUsuario.setClickable(true);

        binding.listViewAltaUsuario.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                // obtenemos el valor de los datos al pulsar el item
                String nombre_posicion = nombreList[i];
                String correo_posicion = correoList[i];
                // guardamos el valor de los datos en las variables iniciales
                correoItem = correo_posicion;
                nombreItem = nombre_posicion;
                // llamamos al metodo para activar el usuario
                activarUsuario();
                // borramos los datos de los arrays (la posicion)
                binding.listViewAltaUsuario.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega un método a tu adapter `ListAdapter.java` para actualizar el listado, este recibiría la nueva lista de datos (Define el tipo y la variable que usas para el listado en tu `Adapter`):

```
   public void actualiza(List< T > dataArrayList) {
        this.dataArrayList;
    }
```

Ahora en tu `OnItemClickListener` no necesitas configurar una lista a tu `Adapter`, ya que lo realizaste previamente, lo que debes realizar es enviar la nueva lista de datos, y posteriormente llamar `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

```
  binding.listViewAltaUsuario.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            // obtenemos el valor de los datos al pulsar el item
            String nombre_posicion = nombreList[i];
            String correo_posicion = correoList[i];
            // guardamos el valor de los datos en las variables iniciales
            correoItem = correo_posicion;
            nombreItem = nombre_posicion;
            // llamamos al metodo para activar el usuario
            activarUsuario();
            // borramos los datos de los arrays (la posicion)

            //**binding.listViewAltaUsuario.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            listAdapter.actualiza(dataArrayList);
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Buenas estoy haciendo lo que me dices con el metodo  
    public void actualiza(List< ArrayList > dataArrayList) {
        this.dataArrayList;
    }                                                                                                                                      pero me dice que not a statement en la linea de this.dataArrayList

Comment: Es que te comentaba que editaras de acuerdo a tu código, agrega tu adapter para decirte exactamente como realizarlo por favor. @jose22

Comment: Ya funciona perfecto. Ahora el problema lo tengo con un dialog que quiero que según pulse en aceptar o cancelar, me devuelva true o false. Pero al mismo ejecutarlo se me va a la opcion de cancelar directo y no se por que. Subire un post sino doy con la tecla. MUCHAS GRACIAS

Comment: perdona, podrias echarme una mano con este post que he subido que no doy con la tecla.   https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/599190/searchview-filtra-datos-pero-no-actualiza-lista-en-pantalla