# Searchview filtra datos pero no actualiza lista en pantalla

Tags: java, android

Buenas tengo el siguiente codigo en una aplicacion Android con Java.
El caso esque tengo un searchview para poder buscar los datos con el siguiente metodo:
El cual lo ejecuto en onQueryTextChange(String newText)

```
public void filtraDatos(String texto) {
        ArrayList<ListData> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ListData list : dataArrayList) {
            if (list.getNombre().toLowerCase().contains(texto.toLowerCase())){
                filteredList.add(list);
            }
        }
        if (filteredList.isEmpty()){
            Utilidades.tostadaCorta(getBaseContext(), "No hay datos").show();
        }else {
            // cargamos la lista
            listAdapter.actualizaLista(filteredList);
        }
    }
```

Y en el adaptador para la lista tengo lo siguiente para actualizar

```
public void actualizaLista(List<ListData> dataArray) {
        // asignamos el valor de la variable
        this.dataArray = dataArray;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

El caso esque los datos me los filtra bien, pues depuro y me los guarda en el arrayList creado en el metodo de la clase principal, pero cuando intento actualizar la lista, esta se queda igual.
Sin embargo cuando elimino algun dato con el metodo hago la misma llamada para actualizar la lista y aqui si me los actualiza. Alguien podria ayudarme.

Imagen del arrayList que guarda los datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen una vez pasado el arrayFiltrado y notificado el cambio al controlador:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede apreciar lo hace bien, pero la pantalla del telefono donde esta la lista se queda igual no cambia

Comment: Hola Jose, acabo de ver tu  pregunta, dices que la lista filtrada la envías a tu método  actualizaLista() pero no hace nada, esto me parece raro! , te sugiero revisar que filteredList en verdad tiene una lista de contenido diferente

Comment: Buenas tardes. La lista original (por asi decirlo) es dataArrayList, entonces lo que hago es crear otro arrayList (filteredList) y en este guardo los valores que coinciden con lo que escribo en el SearchView. Y este ultimo el filteredList (un array distinto al original) es el que le paso al metodo de actualizar lista. Porque con el arrayData no se como filtrar los datos. Por que con listAdapter.getFilter().filter(texto a buscar) tampoco me filtra, se queda en blanco y no hace nada

Comment: He añadido dos imagenes de la depuracion del codigo, como ves funciona pero en la pantalla no se actualiza nada.

Answer (score 0):

a mi nunca me ha funcionado el notifyDataSetChanged() ya que el adapter sabe que cambiaron los datos, pero nunca los "repinta"
lo que hago siempre es recargar el Adaptador con el nuevo ArrayList
entonces podrias hacer algo como:

```
public void actualizaLista(List<ListData> dataArray) {
    tuAdapter.clear() //limpia el adaptador queda vacio
    tuAdapter.setAdapter(adapter);  //carga el nuevo array con los nuevos datos
}
```